# Handling video call state in Flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am currently working on flutter app that main core feature is video calling.
I am using **Agora.Io** SDK for video calling. and I also implement FCM for Video call acceptance Screen and that is working fine but my question is how to handle that video call when the user receives an actual call  and  resume that call when the call is finished (like resume and pause )

how should I put that video call on hold and continue?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: How you invoke a call when receiving notification from FCM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pauseAudio()` and `resumeAudio()` function for your use case. You can find detailed description about these functions over here: https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-flutter-documentation

Comment: Instead of linking to the solution, it is better to copy the relevant parts of the link into this answer, in addition.